# Why I can't fill anything in my form in React?

Tags: reactjs, email, react-hooks

So I have a form, and I need users to fill this form and when they send a message, it should come to my gmail. I use EmailJS service for this.
So my form looks like this:
[image]

So as you see, users can send me messages, and my code looks like this:

Usestate for sending data:

```
const [toSend, setToSend] = useState({
        from_name: '',
        to_name: '',
        message: '',
        reply_to: '',
        subject: ''
      });
```

onSubmit function:

```
const onSubmit = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        send(
            'service_id',
            'template_id',
            toSend,
            'user_id'
          )
            .then((response) => {
              console.log('SUCCESS!', response.status, response.text);
            })
            .catch((err) => {
              console.log('FAILED...', err);
            });
        reset();
      };
```

handleChange function:

```
const handleChange = (e) => {
        setToSend({ ...toSend, [e.target.name]: e.target.value });
      };
```

useform hook:

```
const {register, handleSubmit, formState: { errors }, reset, trigger} = useForm();
```

Whole form:

```
<form onSubmit={handleSubmit(onSubmit)}>
                    <input type="text"
                     placeholder="Name"
                     name="from_name"
                     value={toSend.from_name}
                     onChange={handleChange}
                      id="name" {...register('name', { required: "Name is required" })}
                    onKeyUp={() => {
                        trigger("name");
                      }}/>
                    {errors.name && (<span className="danger_text">{errors.name.message}</span>)}
                    <input type="text"
                     placeholder="Email"
                     name="reply_to"
                     value={toSend.reply_to}
                     onChange={handleChange}
                      id="email"  {...register("email", { required: "Email is Required" ,
                pattern: {
                  value: /^[A-Z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Z0-9.-]+\.[A-Z]{2,}$/i,
                  message: "Invalid email address",
                }})}
                onKeyUp={() => {
                  trigger("email");
                }}
              />
              {errors.email && (
                <small className="danger_text">{errors.email.message}</small>
              )}
                    <input type="text"
                     placeholder=
                     "Subject" 
                     id="subj"
                     name="subject"
                     value={toSend.subject}
                     onChange={handleChange}/>
                    <input type="text"
                     placeholder="Message"
                      id="msg"
                      name="message"
                      value={toSend.message}
                      onChange={handleChange}
                       {...register('msg', { required: true })}/>
                    {errors.msg && (<small className="danger_text">Enter your message</small>)}
                    <input type="submit" className="btn_red" value="Send a message"></input>
                </form>
```

So my problem is that I can't fill anything in inputs. When I try to type something it just doesn't type in, I'm guessing it has something to do with "value=.." in all inputs, but I'm not sure what's exactly the problem here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to define `onChnage`, `value`, `onKeyUp` on your inputs, when you call `register` on input, it returns `onChange,onBlur,ref`, then `react-hook-forms` will control the values by `ref`. so below example should solve your problem:

```
import { useForm } from 'react-hook-form';
...
function MyComp() {
  const {
    register,
    handleSubmit,
    formState: { errors },
    reset,
  } = useForm();

  const onSubmit = (toSend) => {
    send(
        'service_id',
        'template_id',
        toSend,
        'user_id'
      )
      .then((response) => {
          console.log('SUCCESS!', response.status, response.text);
        })
      .catch((err) => {
          console.log('FAILED...', err);
       });
    reset();
  };

  return (
    <form onSubmit={handleSubmit(onSubmit)}>
      <input
        type="text"
        placeholder="Name"
        name="from_name"
        id="name"
        {...register('from_name', { required: 'Name is required' })}
      />
      {errors.from_name && (
        <span className="danger_text">{errors.from_name.message}</span>
      )}
      <input
        type="text"
        placeholder="Email"
        name="reply_to"
        id="email"
        {...register('reply_to', {
          required: 'Email is Required',
          pattern: {
            value: /^[A-Z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Z0-9.-]+\.[A-Z]{2,}$/i,
            message: 'Invalid email address',
          },
        })}
      />
      {errors.reply_to && (
        <small className="danger_text">{errors.reply_to.message}</small>
      )}
      <input
        type="text"
        placeholder="Subject"
        id="subj"
        name="subject"
        {...register('subject')}
      />
      <input
        type="text"
        placeholder="Message"
        id="msg"
        name="message"
        {...register('message', { required: true })}
      />
      {errors.message && <small className="danger_text">Enter your message</small>}
      <input type="submit" className="btn_red" value="Send a message"></input>
    </form>
  );
}
```

BTW, consider that `register` works with input's `name`, not `id`.

Comment: hi! should i remove the useState? cause in your example it's not present

Comment: Hi, Yes, you don't need it, form's value will pass to onSubmit by `react-hooks-form`.